# Is it possible to create a URL link to a website on the home screen?

Tags: browser, home-screen-shortcuts

Is it possible to create an icon on my desktop home screen (Android 2.1 Samsung Galaxy) that I can tap to fire up the browser to a specific web site?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create it as a bookmark in the Android browser. Then, long-press your home screen and choose the "Bookmark" option. Select the bookmark you made and *Voilà*!

---

For newer versions of Android, assuming you're using the Chrome browser:

1. Go to the URL you want in the browser
2. Open the menu (three vertical dots) and choose "Add to Home screen"
3. Confirm the title you want to give the icon and click "Add"

*Et Voilà*! You now have an icon on your home screen that will open your browser to that URL.

Comment: Why doesnt this work for me? I have android 5.0. Is this feature gone?

Comment: @the_prole: Hardly. Still works for me in Android 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with adding bookmarks to the home screen with my new Samsung Galaxy Fame, using Android 4.1.2. The 'Add to home screen' option seemed to have disappeared.

The solution seems to be to use the stock browser (not Chrome).
Create the bookmark. 
Long press the new bookmark and select the 'Create Shortcut' option. 
This places the bookmark on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that the currently updated browsers such as Chrome for Android and Firefox offers exporting any site opened in a tab as a shortcut to home screen. There is now no need to create a bookmark to make a home screen shortcut.

- For Chrome, simply open the website, tap Menu button and choose "Add to Home screen".
- For Firefox, open the website, tap Menu button, go to **Page** and choose "Add to Home Screen".