# Is it possible to create a shortcut that launches a web page in Firefox when using another browser as default?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, home-screen-shortcuts, firefox-for-android

I have a web page that I visit that I'd like to open in Firefox via a home screen shortcut (it uses SVG, which isn't supported by the default browser).    Firefox doesn't show in the list of possible shortcuts, nor do I see any option in Firefox to create one.    Btw, I like Firefox, but I'm not ready to make it my default browser yet, so I really want to continue to use the stock Browser for everything but this one shortcut.

I'm running Firefox 7.0.1 / Fennec 7.0.1 on Gingerbread 2.3.4

Comment: Edited to mention that I don't wish to change default browser at this time.    Also, for those that will recommend Dolphin HD, it doesn't support SVG yet either.

Comment: Related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28607/non-default-browser-for-specific-web-page

Comment: Is the problem still relevant or has been solved?

Comment: @Firelord - wow, that was a while back... I just tested with Firefox 40.0.3 on Android 4.4.4 KitKat -- a  Home Screen shortcut saved with Firefox launches with Firefox, even though another browser (Chrome in this case) is the default.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Firefox for Android, but if it is the same as other Android browsers, then you should be able to create a [home screen bookmark](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2086/482) and choose which browser to open the bookmark in (unless you previously saved defaults, then you need to [clear the defaults first](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/11875/482#11879)).

Comment: Thanks Lie.   At this point, I don't want to change my default browser; I was hoping I could do it for a specific shortcut.